# issue on Grails Mail 1.0 Plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

I am currently using `Grails Mail 1.0 plugin` in my project. I used it `to send verification link to registrant's email address`. Unfortunately, the sent verification link is not clickable on some webmail services like `hotmail` and `yahoo mail`. I have also encountered same problem with other web browsers like `mozilla` and `google chrome`. Is this really a bug on the said plugin? Please help!

Comment: A good way to try is to send an email with the same content that your app-generated emails have but from a normal email client. That way if you see problems in the same mail clients you know that the problem is the client or your text/html. Of there is no problem then you know that the plugin is not generating the email correctly.

In short: experiment to isolate the problem.

Comment: Also, posting some code might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this really a bug on the said plugin?

Almost certainly not. I use the same plugin to send HTML emails and they render fine in Yahoo mail.

In general, you shouldn't rely on links in HTML email being rendered correctly, because some email programs may be configured to only read emails in plain text format. Also, the rendering of HTML content varies wildly from one email program to another.

For these reasons, you should generally provide a plain-text fallback, e.g.

> To register, [click here](http://www.example.org). If you're using
>   a rubbish email program, you won't be able to click the link, so
>   copy-paste the following link into your browser's address bar:
>   http://www.example.org